# div Element changes position (margin) of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:

I have a div element with a background image which position is exactly like I want. But when I add a child div into it, it changes. (Theres a small margin at top)

I want to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

**CSS Code:**

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: green;
    background: url(../images/backround_red.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

div#mainWrapper {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70em;
    height:100%;
    background: url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 4em;
}

div#loginWrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**screenshots:**

without the childdiv:
[image]

with the childdiv:
[image]

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DUtb4/

Comment: change your child's `margin-top` to `padding-top`

Comment: This is usually caused by margin-top of the child element. please add your markup and maybe jsFiddle so I can know for sure

Comment: Do you have a live example we can see?

Comment: ok here is a JSFiddle, I have used some random google pictures, but the problem is the same and visible:
http://jsfiddle.net/DUtb4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must override the ***default*** `16px` of `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of a `<p>` element.

Add this in your CSS

```
#loginWrapper > p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DUtb4/3/

Answer (score 1):

You put this on top of css , that will help you .

```
* {
   margin  : 0;
   padding : 0;
}
```

[this is here done changes on your content](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/xeavD/)

Comment: This should be used only to debug, it is an heavy and dangerous selector... it is saying apply `margin 0` and `padding 0` to everything, everywhere... ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Or you can do it like that here, in current situation , use it on div element. padding:0 and margin:0; or make a quickfix class . and put inside it maring and padding 0, and use where it needed..

Comment: Of course, you can do anything you want, or need, to solve problems. I was simply suggesting that you should put that disclaimer in your description, warning readers that this "will help you", but for "debugging purposes only", clearly stating to not leave this in production environment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the mainWrapper to:

```
div#mainWrapper {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Added a 0 to the beginning */
    width: 70em;
    height:100%;
    background: url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 4em;
}
```

Also add
    padding: 0;
to the body tag.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it sadly didn't solve the problem.